# Type casting several dictionaries generated from a loop into a single list

Tags: python

I have a for loop that create several dictionaries as an output. I'd like to capture all those dictionaries into a single list. How to do this? In the example below, the loop generates hundreds of dicts when you print out row. I'd like to encapsulate that entire dict output as a single list. My code is below but instead is dumping out numerous lists and dicts.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for row in reader:
    print row #for debug
    for key, value in row.iteritems():
        temp=[key,value]
        alist.extend(temp)
        print alist
```

alist should look like this `[{k,v},{k2,v2},{k3,v3}...]`

Comment: I see two issues; one is your code is not creating any dictionaries and the second is `{k,v}` is not valid dictionary syntax.

Comment: That is not correct, the code is creating dictionaries because of csv.dictreader. Try it yourself. f is just a csv file with some columns and data inside.

Comment: If you want lists instead of dictionaries, why you `csv.DictReader` rather than just `csv.reader` (which returns lists)? It seems like you're making work for yourself.

Comment: I want a list of dictionaries as my alist output shows.

Comment: You've got the wrong syntax for a dictionary literal. `{k,v}` is a two-element set, not a single element dictionary. It's also not very clear where the `k` and `v` values are coming from in your desired output. Are they all from the same row of the CSV file? How does the data from the next row of the file look in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your life simpler by just doing the following:

```
import csv

with open('somefile.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
   rows = list(reader)
```

`rows` will be a list of all rows from the csv file, and each row will be represented as a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.. could not figure out how to typecast dicts into a list.

Comment: Well, to be clear - that's not what this is doing (ie, typecasting). It is simply passing the generator `reader` to the `list()` method. It is the same as doing `rows = [i for i in reader]`